# How do I apply the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license?

Tags: cc-by-sa

I would like to create a github repository with [this](https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf) edited and in a special presentation format. How should I do it? What files the repository should contain and with what contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copyright licenses are based on copyright law. As far as copyright is concerned, a repository isn't a thing and copyright licenses generally don't mention the term 'repository' at all or even a term that is similar.
For copyright purposes, a file is a computer term for how data is organized and which typically holds (part of) a copyrightable work.

Thus, copyright licenses generally have very little requirements about what files are present in a repository. They mainly have requirements about what information is given to the recipients of the work.

For software, there are certain conventions about what files to include in your repository, but those conventions are not universally accepted nor is there a legal reason to follow them.

For non-software works (which the "Git Internals PDF" is and which the CC licenses target) the use of a repository is not a given, nor that a work might consist of multiple files. For that reason, it is sufficient if your repository contains just a single file with the final rendered version of the document, as long as that document contains an attribution of "Git Internals PDF" and is under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license itself. [As explained by Creative Commons itself](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/attribution/), an ideal attribution contains the title, a link to where the original can be obtained, the author of the original and the license (with a link) under which you obtained the original work.

If you decide to treat your work more like software, with a source code that the final document can be rendered from, that final rendered document should meet the requirements of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license without the need for a separate "license file" because that is the common expectation with literary works.

Comment: And shouldn't I create a readme file with the authors of original material? Or it is only sufficient to include the final rendered version of the document?

Comment: @xralf, a readme file (and a license file) is a convention for software projects. The CC licenses were designed to also work for printed photographs or printed books. For those kinds of works, a readme file would be very inconvenient.

Comment: So, if I understand it well, all I have to do is to include the original pdf in my repository?

Comment: The CC licenses don't require a particular form unless it's the no-derivative license... then you may distribute but not alter it. It's important that the recipeients get a clear indication of the license status and authors of the work. It does not need to be a PDF. It could be in the readme or a license file which accompanies the software. It could be in the splash of a title screen, in the about section...

Comment: Especially with the CC licenses it's often a good idea to think about "how would I want to see myself credited in the work shipped, if I were the author of the work I use and require to get attribution"

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau It's on a good way for accepting, but could you please clarify me "the appropriate attribution" yet?

Comment: @xralf, Added something on attributuions

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Could you please look into the document if there is an ideal attribution? Isn't there a problem, that in the document is written $9? But [here](https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf) is written `Scott and Pluralsight have generously open sourced it under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license.`

Comment: @xralf, maybe there is a misunderstanding. *You* should include an attribution to "Git Internals PDF" in your document to acknowledge that you based your work on that and to make it clear what gave you the right to do so. "Git Internals PDF" does not need to contain an attribution as it appears to be an original work published by the author.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau OK, so I should create a repository with CC license, include in it a original PDF, and my material will be more files, so I will include an attribution in one of them? Or should be e.g. file attribution.txt in the root directory? Is it OK?

Comment: @planetmaker So, I can use the readme file for attribution, when I altered the original pdf into more files?

Comment: Sounds like a plan

Comment: @planetmaker It's not finished yet. But maybe I will use rather the about section for the attribution, as you said. I noticed that people do it this way.

Comment: A good guide is also: where you put your copyright notices, put also the copyright notices of everything you depend on - like these CC assets

Comment: @planetmaker Now, I created the [repository](https://github.com/lucidl/git_internals_tdg). Is the attribution OK?

Comment: I guess the last portion of the README.md is intended as the attribution, but without the knowledge of this question, I would have thought that it identifies you as original author. A better attribution would be a sentence like "Based on *Git Internals* by *Scott Chacon*, licensed under *CC BY-SA*" with the parts marked as italics here being links as you used them.

Comment: @xralf I can only agree with Bart van Ingen Schenau: it reads now like you are Scott Chacon. Write it as "Based on 'Git Internals' by Scott Chacon, licensed under CC-BY-SA" with the links as set.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thank you both, I corrected it.